# Colleague is negative and does not acknowledge me

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, team, conflict, teamwork

I have the following situation. I am new to a team but not new to the project have worked in it for couple of years but I was away on different assignment again for 3 years. Now I am back in new team and I face the following situation with colleague:

I am looking through a code and say ok that can be done better because in my opinion it is breaking single responsibility principle. Then a discussion starts where all sorts of directions are discussed which are related to the original topic but only vaguely. The topic suddenly becomes super complex and seems like we have some sort of disagreement according to the colleague when I actually don't see a disagreement at all, just an overblown discussion. My colleague starts talking and forgets to stop the discussion takes like 1 our an half :)

It appears that the colleague is all the time seeking dispute with me for some reason and he never acknowledges if I say something that he agrees upon.

I am a bit afraid he will act as a stopper to any more serious initiative I take. I am considered by the product owner and the team lead as the more senior colleague since I have worked for the organization for longer and have more projects behind my back. On pure years of experience we are equal and we are of the same age.

How to deal with negative colleague seeking disputes ?

Comment: `I am a bit afraid he will act as a stopper to any more serious initiative I take` - Does he actually have the power to do that? If not, maybe ignore it and focus on your work and on the things you can control and influence.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that he resents your swooping in to reclaim your mantle of senior on “his” project, in which case I’d talk to him about that, and then if that fails the two of you can talk to your manager.

But it’s also very possible that after an absence of three years, you don’t understand the project as well as you think; there may be complexities that you don’t appreciate. If you think something should be changed, you might try to make the change yourself (on a branch, of course!) and then ask the team if it isn’t an improvement. You may find while trying to make the change that it isn’t as simple as you thought.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking through a code and say ok that can be done better

That is your first and the most important mistake. If you consider that it is a big problem, just create a ticket  bug report / whatever. It would then be analyzed by the responsible people in the project and eventually fixed. If the  decision is to not fix it, then just move forward.

> Colleague ... does not acknowledge me

That is another problem, you take it personally. You make it about yourself. Please rethink the things and understand that whatever you and your colleagues do is just a job.

> It appears that the colleague is all the time seeking dispute with me

As I understand, he is not seeking dispute with you. He is just defending his work and his workproduct. Even if you are more senior, he is still owner of his job, and he has his rights as an owner. The project manager, together with the core team (including requirements engineer, architect, testing leader...) have the job to judge the situations and make the appropriate decisions.

Comment: I have to disagree with your answer. He does not own his job as by the agile practices the owership is common. I as a personhave the right to interact with collegues and share opinions. Th code I was commenting was a third persons code and is not relevant to anything he has coded.